# Zendesk App - Agent Call Activity

Tags: api, zendesk

I'm trying to create an app for my Zendesk that I can put into the `ticket_sidebar` that will show which of my agents are available on the phones.

The information that I need is already in Zendesk under Admin/channels/voice/Call Activity. Ideally, I would like to have a cut down version of the **Agent Activity, Last 24hours** section so that in the app it will show the Agents who are on phone support and then the status.

There are three status that I would like to use, they are:

- Available
- Offline
- On Call

I have made a start with just getting the app created and doing a simple hello function to great the current users.

I am new to this, and any help or guidance that anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I finally got this work.

It refreshes upon clicking on the app, and shows if my agents are available, on a call or offline